# How can I implement "AI Virtual Furniture Staging" in a React Native app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-lite

I want to implement AI Interior Designing in my Real Estate app built in react native.
I need functionality like apps MyRoom etc. OR websites like https://www.virtualstagingai.app/ OR https://decorai.io/

Do anyone know something about it?

Right now, I'm only searching and I found that with Tensorflow, I need to train a model for image processing. I also tried to found some paid APIs but found nothing.
Please anyone guide me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For advanced app features like this, I prefer working with native APIs rather than a framework like React Native.

- E.g. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/

But if that's not an option, you may have some luck with a third party React Native library that provides bindings.

- For iOS & Android: https://github.com/ViroCommunity/viro/

Comment: Thank you for answering my query. Actually, I found two websites regarding this that provide APIs.